# JOIN or not in SQL statement

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have a `SELECT` statement, and I use table name such as :

```
select cust.name from cust,order where cust.id = order.id ;
```

I didn't use a `JOIN` statement, 
Question is the given statement is `JOIN` or not?

Comment: That is not a valid query. Please give a valid query that you have successfully run & be very clear when you ask your question. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please give the results of your research. PS An implicit join is `x , y` in `from` & an explicit or keyword join is  or `x ...  join y` or `x ... join y on ...` in a `from`. Or one might sloppily call a whole query containing one or more of those a join.

Comment: Ok, you edited. But you didn't act on all of my last comment. What is your question? What do you mean, is this a join? What do you think it is? Why aren't you sure? Why do you think it might not be? Are you wondering what `,` does? What do you think `,` means & does?--What does your research, manual & googling tell you? Right now you are not using enough words. You have accepted an answer that says "no"--Why? Do you think it answers your quesion? They should not have answered when your question had invalid code & didn't make sense.

Comment: @PersianGulf . . . `,` *IS* a "join" operator.  It is an archaic way to write `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a join statement.When you want to perform a join you have to select all required tables.

When you select all required tables in `From` and use join `,` in WHERE it becomes `implicit join` as below.

```
select 
  cust.name 
from customer c, [order] o
where c.id = o.id ;
```

When you use join two tables with `JOIN` syntax then it is called `explicit join` as below

```
select 
  cust.name 
from customer c
join [order] o
on c.id = o.id ;
```

Comment: After correcting you, is your query is join or not? my means  if I'm not use join in statement, can be join or not?

Comment: Yes it can be `join` as shown in implicit join example.

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions. The code didn't make sense. So it wasn't clear what they were asking about, because they weren't asking about valid code. Instead leave a comment asking for clarification. You write "If I am correct then"--so you know you are guessing. Now they have edited their question, although it's still not clear what they are trying to ask. Guessing makes a confused mess.

Comment: @PersianGulf . . . This answer is not correct.  `,` is a "join" operator.  It is just obsoleted by proper, explicit, **standard** readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to write a join query using the implicit join syntax.  That should look something like this:

```
select cust.name from cust, order where cust.id = order.id;
```

But actually, `order` is a reserved keyword in just about every version of SQL, so you should escape it, maybe using double quotes:

```
select cust.name from cust, "order" where cust.id = "order".id;
```

However, it is much preferable to use modern, explicit join syntax now, so please use:

```
select cust.name from cust inner join "order" on cust.id = "order".id;
```

And consider renaming your `order` table to something other than a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The `,` is an archaic way of writing `JOIN`s in SQL.  It basically means `CROSS JOIN`, although the semantics are slightly different in the `FROM` clause.

It was replaced in the 1990's -- yes, the last millennium -- by proper, explicit, standard, readable `JOIN` syntax.  As much as I dislike commas, they are part of the SQL language.  I do wish they would be deprecated, but that has not yet occurred (that would mean that newer databases would have no obligation to support the syntax).

I think you know that you should be using:

```
select c.name
from cust c join
     order o
    on c.id = o.id ;
```

(An aside, `order` is a really bad name for a table because it is an Oracle keyword.)

The word "join" can mean multiple things when talking about databases.

1. It can mean the `JOIN` operator, which is a specific operator in the `FROM` clause.
2. It can mean the "join" operation in the `FROM` clause.  By this definition, `,` is a "join" operation, which is equivalent to `CROSS JOIN`.
3. It can mean the combining of data from any multiple tables -- basically using underlying "join" algorithms.  By this definition, `IN`, `EXISTS`, and so on might be "join" operations, even though they are not in the `FROM` clause.